# Как сократить скрипт и убрать дублирование кода?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сократить эту часть кода?

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1080) {
    // если ширина экрана больше 1080 выводить 4 товара
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".center").slick({
            dots: false,
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        });
    });
} else {
    // если ширина экрана меньше 1080 выводить 2 товара
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".center").slick({
            dots: false,
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать дублирование кода можно, допустим так:

```
const slickData = {
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
}

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1080) slickData.slidesToShow = 4;
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".center").slick(slickData);
});
```